# Default Form Field Value not Being Set in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I am trying to populate an input text field with a default value but when the view renders, the default value is not being applied to the input text field.

**Important Details**

I am passing the value into the ViewBag from a controller action

When debugging on the view page, I see that the ViewBag has the default value I need

Can someone tell me if I am setting the default value correctly in the view's input text field?

Thanks

**Here is the input text box that I am trying to populate:**

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchRadius, new { @Value = ViewBag.SearchRadius})
</div>
```

Comment: EditorFor does not have an overload that accepts html attributes.  What's wrong with setting SearchRadius to the value you want in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you changed EditorFor to TextBoxFor it should work because editorfor doesn't have any overloads on what you're trying. **BUT** I recommend setting the default value of `model.SearchRadius` in your controller action instead of setting a dupe viewbag item:

**Controller Action**:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.SearchRadius = "Whatever";
    return View();
}
```

**Razor**:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchRadius)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchRadius, new { @Value = ViewBag.SearchRadius})
</div>
```

Please note **'V'** in @Value; its a capital. For some reason @value dosent seems to work